# What's the different between 'list((x,)).extend([x])' and 'foo=list((x,)); foo.extend([x])'

Tags: python

1. Ran `print(list((1,)).extend([2]))`, the output is `None`.
2. Ran `foo=list((1,)); foo.extend([2]);print(foo)`, the output is `[1, 2]`.

I don't know whats the different, Please help to check it, thanks.

Comment: The first one you're not printing the list, you're printing the return value of `extend` which is none.

Answer (score 1):

The extend() method only modifies the original list. It doesn't return any value. Thus print() couldn't receive anything, and output 'None'.

Answer (score 1):

In the first snippet, you're printing what `extend` returns: `None`. In the second snippet, you're printing `foo`, the list itself.

Or in other words, in the first, you're printing the result of a function call that doesn't return anything. In the second, you're carrying out the `extend` call, *then* printing the list separately.